# Installing Linux without Affecting Windows 7

Tags: linux, grub

I have window 7 installed on my laptop and I can install linux (ubuntu). I just wanted to install it with following conditions.

1. At the time of booting I get option for both OS, but if i delete linux OS it should not effect the booting process of Windows. May be it automatically gain windows bootloader or if its grub, its OK.
2. I am not aware of what is `sda` at the time of installation. Can we create `sdb` without destroying Windows partitions and install linux in this `sdb`. I got free space in my system.

Comment: If you don't need dual booting, you can try VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any problems. Just Burn Ubuntu on Live CD then boot from the Live CD and follow the instructions. Choose install Ubuntu and then after you choose the language the will be three options, install alongside Windows 7, replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu [you don't want this] and something else. So you will want to choose the first or the third option. When you delete Ubuntu you will have to put the automatic repair CD/DVD from Microsoft and click repair. It is the Disc you got with Windows 7.

You can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) the official Ubuntu Documentation. Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64671/how-to-partition-a-disk-for-installing-ubuntu) a link from askubuntu.

Comment: Just to clarify. Ubuntu will replace the windows bootloader with grub, hence the need to run windows repair if you delete Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3 partition setup:

1. Windows
2. Ubuntu
3. GRUB (easiest method, use /boot) - only has to be a 100MB or so

You'll install GRUB to the MBR like normal, but all the configs will be in the third. This way, even if you delete the Ubuntu partition, you can still boot into Windows without having to have a Windows repair disk handy.

Make sure to have GRUB boot into Windows by default.

The obvious downsides are:

- You'll always have that GRUB partition
- Burn another partition (unless you're using GPT, you're limited to 4 partitions)

Comment: You can always create an extended partition. the second downside is gone

Comment: @Kamal - Right, but if the GRUB partition is placed at the end, it will have to be moved because extended partitions must be the last partition.

Comment: My system has an extended partition which is not the last partition. The only restriction I came across is that you can’t create more than one extended partition. Which is never required

Answer (score 0):

Another, but much slower, alternative is using wubi.

This method retains Windows Boot Loader but makes boot process slow

Nevertheless, here's how you do it

- Burn Ubuntu on live CD/USB drive
- Open the CD and run wubi.exe
- And follow the instructions...